# neo4j java driver problems when using ssl through awselb

Tags: java, ssl, neo4j

I' am using neo4j community version 3.1.1 and enterprise edition version 3.0.1 with ssl configured through awselb  . 
To connection i use neo4j java driver version 1.0.0 
After i configure ssl and connection through awselb i have problem with opened files they are growing so fast and their amount not reduced . 
[image]
Code in app to use ssl

```
GraphDatabase.driver(host, authToken, Config.build().withEncryptionLevel(Config.EncryptionLevel.REQUIRED).toConfig());
```

I try upgrade neo4j driver to version 1.1.1  and 1.1.2 but have another problem : 
when i do query to neo4j periodically all is fine and i get data from db but periodically i have 500 error and in app log this exception

**Without ssl i dont have problems**

```
org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ServiceUnavailableException: SSL Connection terminated while receiving data. This can happen due to network instabilities, or due to restarts of the database.
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.security.TLSSocketChannel.channelRead(TLSSocketChannel.java:170)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.security.TLSSocketChannel.unwrap(TLSSocketChannel.java:229)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.security.TLSSocketChannel.read(TLSSocketChannel.java:419)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.BufferingChunkedInput.readNextPacket(BufferingChunkedInput.java:409)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.BufferingChunkedInput.readChunkSize(BufferingChunkedInput.java:345)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.BufferingChunkedInput.read(BufferingChunkedInput.java:247)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.BufferingChunkedInput.fillScratchBuffer(BufferingChunkedInput.java:216)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.BufferingChunkedInput.readByte(BufferingChunkedInput.java:110)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.packstream.PackStream$Unpacker.unpackStructHeader(PackStream.java:430)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.PackStreamMessageFormatV1$Reader.read(PackStreamMessageFormatV1.java:398)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketClient.receiveOne(SocketClient.java:176)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketConnection.receiveOne(SocketConnection.java:214)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.ConcurrencyGuardingConnection.receiveOne(ConcurrencyGuardingConnection.java:166)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.PooledConnection.receiveOne(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalStatementResult.tryFetchNext(InternalStatementResult.java:324)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalStatementResult.hasNext(InternalStatementResult.java:191)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalStatementResult.list(InternalStatementResult.java:261)
    at carx.neo4j.beans.services.Neo4jClient.getResults(Neo4jClient.java:90)
    at carx.mpserver.beans.services.impl.StorageFacadeServiceImpl.getLastTopPeriodIds(StorageFacadeServiceImpl.java:395)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:97)
    at carx.web.spark.beans.aspect.abased.ProfilerUtilAspect.profile(ProfilerUtilAspect.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor87.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:620)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:609)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.getLastTopPeriodIds(Unknown Source)
    at carx.mpserver.beans.services.impl.TopServiceImpl.getPeriodInfo(TopServiceImpl.java:265)
    at carx.mpserver.beans.services.impl.TopServiceImpl.list(TopServiceImpl.java:162)
    at carx.mpserver.beans.services.impl.MpServerUserApiImpl.topList(MpServerUserApiImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor142.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.topList(Unknown Source)
    at carx.mpserver.beans.bootstraps.CarxMpRoutesServiceImpl.lambda$initRoutes$14(CarxMpRoutesServiceImpl.java:102)
    at carx.web.spark.beans.service.impl.BaseSparkRoutesService$ContextAwareAndToJsonRoute.handle(BaseSparkRoutesService.java:292)
    at spark.RouteImpl$1.handle(RouteImpl.java:61)
    at spark.http.matching.Routes.execute(Routes.java:61)
    at spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:128)
    at spark.servlet.SparkFilter.doFilter(SparkFilter.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:201)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1158)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1090)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Have you tried forcing a GC cycle through Jconsole or in the code and seen if that releases some filehandles/sockets?  Is it possible that in your code you are not doing a release somewhere to do with the sockets/neo4j objects?  This could be when an exception occurs for some other reason like the socket is closed on the other end.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for you answer . I try force GC cycle from Jconsole and let you know about the results. Maybe you are right i'll search  places in code where neo4j objects need to be  released

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my Rest API. Initially I have instantiated GraphDatabase.driver(..) each and every API call which is recommended. Then later I instantiated  GraphDatabase.driver(..) in constructor and reused it across each and every APIs. Then no issues encountered.